# Other SDK or REST API for actions on Google?

Tags: actions-on-google

Is it possible or in the Roadmap to develop your own Action on Google without to use API.ai or the NodeJS SDK?

Comment: I've added an answer, but will also comment here - there is an unofficial Java/Kotlin SDK that is the most complete option for JVM.  Docs/readme will be updated soon, and it is ready for use.  https://github.com/TicketmasterMobileStudio/actions-on-google-kotlin

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is already possible: I built a very small example of a Conversation Action in Java with [Vert.x](http://vertx.io/): https://github.com/Ithildir/actions-on-google-vertx-sample

Here you can find more information about the HTTP protocol: https://developers.google.com/actions/reference/conversation

Comment: Just be aware that Google is pushing aggressively the development to api.ai. You can use any languages to receive/generate json without api.ai but it may not last. Google already crippled the node sdk to force you to use api.ai.

Comment: Thanks Andreas, I will take a look to it. Bela, I don't like graphical interfaces as many developers do, so if Google/api.ai don't provide a simple interface, Google Actions will fail

Answer (score 2):

You can implement an Actions on Google compatible webhook using JAX-RS. For example, this Java library models the HTTP protocol that Google documented: https://github.com/l0s/google-actions-conversation-api . See the documentation for more details. An example implementation looks like this:

```
@Path("/webhook")
@Consumes("application/json")
@Produces("application/json")
@POST
public ConversationResponse handle(final ConversationRequest request,
        @Context final HttpServletResponse servletResponse) {
    servletResponse.setHeader("Google-Assistant-API-Version", "v1");

    final SpeechResponse speechResponse = new SpeechResponse();
    speechResponse.setTextToSpeech("Hello!");
    final FinalResponse finalResponse = new FinalResponse();
    finalResponse.setSpeechResponse(speechResponse);
    final ConversationResponse response = new ConversationResponse();
    response.setConversationToken(request.getConversationToken());
    response.setFinalResponse(finalResponse);
    return response;
}
```

Note that you would need to configure the JSON serialiser/deserialiser ignore unknown properties during deserialisation and to exclude null or empty fields during serialisation.

You do not need to use the library necessarily, but it gives you an idea of how to implement the webhook with a servlet. Also, this approach (with or without the library) does not need to be used with JAX-RS necessarily. The same technique can be applied to a serverless solution such as AWS API Gateway with Lambda.

Comment: Thanks Carlos, I use a lot JAX-RS, it's really useful for quick development of REST API. I'm looking for a Go implementation and this respository is good source of inspiration

Comment: There also is a port of the official SDK to Java/Kotlin.  It has matching API and all functionality of the official.  Available here https://github.com/TicketmasterMobileStudio/actions-on-google-kotlin

Answer (score 0):

Now there is another option for Kotlin/Java.  This is an open source port of the official Actions on Google SDK.  The official node.js SDK supports both API.ai and Actions SDK (direct integration), and the Kotlin/Java one does as well.  It is under development, but is nearing 100% complete and more documentation/examples will be coming.
https://github.com/TicketmasterMobileStudio/actions-on-google-kotlin